# Vector space to $\mathbb{R^3}$ isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The space of quadratic polynomials V with real coefficients.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, u = u_{1}+u_{2}t+u_{3}t^{2}$ and $v=v_{1}+v_{2}t+v_{3}t^{2}$,
then define
$\alpha u := \alpha u_{1}+\alpha u_{2} t+\alpha u_{3}t^{2}$,

u+v is done pointwise.

I want to show that an isomorphism exists from V to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

However, this seems impossible.
First off, I know I need to show a homomorphism from V to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
Then, a bijection from V to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Without any further information provided by the question, I define

$L:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

$u \mapsto \left ( \bar{u}_{1},\bar{u}_{2},\bar{u}_{3} \right )$

which appears to be correct.
But it seems as though the question is making an assumption that I must know of certain assumption to be made. 
I spent quite a while pulling my hair out over this question.
Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$(u_1, u_2, u_3) \mapsto u_1 t^2 + u_2 t+ u_3$$ is the isomorphism. Its inverse is $$u_1 t^2 + u_2 t+ u_3 \mapsto (u_1, u_2, u_3)$$ Now, why do you say that "this seems impossible"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: two finite dimensional vector spaces $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if and only if dim($A$) = dim($B$)

Comment: Thanks but I used the kernel of L to determined that L is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

@saldukoo 2 finite dimensional vector spaces $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if and only if $$wo vector spaces $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if and only if $dim(A) = dim(B)$.